# Parsing option symbols

Tags: python, regex

I think I have this working, but I'm not sure it's completely accurate.

I'm trying to parse Option Symbols. An Option Symbol is made up of 4 parts:

1. Root Symbol (up to 6 characters)
2. Expiration Date (yymmdd)
3. Option Type (1 character)
4. Strike price (8 digits)

After parsing the following examples, the results should be as follows:

1. C020216P00035000

   - Root Symbol ='C'
   - Expiration Date = datetime.date(2002, 2, 16)
   - Option Type = P
   - Strike Price = int(00035000) x .001 = 35.00
2. P020216C00040000

   - Root Symbol = 'P'
   - Expiration Date = datetime.date(2002, 2, 16)
   - Option Type = C
   - Strike Price = int(00040000) x .001 = 40.00
3. SBC020216C00030000

   - Root Symbol = 'SBC'
   - Expiration Date = datetime.date(2002, 2, 16)
   - Option Type = C
   - Strike Price = int(00030000) x .001 = 30.00

I'm using the following code:

```
import re
import datetime as dt

opra_symbol = re.compile(r'(^[^0-9]+)').search(OPRA).group()

opra_expiry = dt.datetime.strptime(re.compile(r'\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}').search(OPRA).group(), '%y%m%d').date()

opra_cp = re.compile(r'([CP])').search(re.compile(r'([CP]\d+$)').search(OPRA).group()).group()

opra_price = int(re.compile(r'(\d+)$').search(OPRA).group()) * .001
```

Is this the best way of getting my results? I'm mostly concerned with the nested regex expression for the Option Type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say the date, option type and price are all fixed length fields, so you can do:

```
opra_symbol = OPRA[:-15]

opra_expiry = dt.datetime.strptime(OPRA[-15:-9]).date()

opra_cp = OPRA[-9]

opra_price = int(OPRA[-8:]) * .001
```

Comment: of course. thanks. by the way, I changed opra_expiry line to opra_expiry = dt.datetime.strptime(OPRA[-15:-9], '%y%m%d').date()

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you can simplify it to the single regex:

```
    matcher = re.compile(r'^(.+)([0-9]{6})([PC])([0-9]+)$')
    groups = matcher.search(option)
```

Then symbol, expiry, type and price are in `groups[0]`, `groups[1]`, `groups[2]` and `groups[3]` respectively. The expiry is guaranteed to be in `yymmdd` format, hence the `{6}` qualifier. You may want to add a `{8}` length qualifier to the price.

Comment: That looks great. I couldn't get groups[n] to work, however. I got groups.group(n) to work. I don't know if it matters, but please let me know if I'm missing something.  Thanks for your help.